# i want to add username in url when someone see the profile of a user in php

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

i want to make a system in which when someone wants to search a registered user he/she just search from website url. its little confusing..i give an example:
in facebook.com, when a entered http://facebook.com/john_corner, the registered user john_corner's profile is displayed. 
How can i get this in my website? 
please give me a direction what to do? any help,code,suggestion, and useful links are very appreciated.

thanks in advance.

Comment: facebook also uses unique key appended with name to prevent duplication of url,you can get this key from your database primary key id

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is URL `rewriting`.

Most webservers support it more or less, apache and nginx however, do.

In case you're using apache, check the `mod_rewrite` docs: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Short discription: You set rules to map `readable urls` to existing files, for instance, yoursite.com/(.*) to index.php?username=$1.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with rewrite

```
RewriteEngine       On
RewriteRule   ^(.*)?/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)   http://%{HTTP_HOST}/index.php?username=$1 [R]
```

You can do short urls to convert to full urls this way too.

For apache [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/)

For IIS [URL Rewrite Module](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-the-url-rewrite-module/)